# PL/SQL Function Json parsing error with google maps api

Tags: sql, json, function, plsql, google-api

I am trying to create a function that accepts a postcode, calls the google api then parses it and returns a sdo_geometry (longitude & latitude), how ever i am unable to get this function to work and not sure where i am going wrong, i did make one mistake since posting but corrected i still get a parse error.

Any help or suggestions for other methods would be greatful. also not sure why im down voted but i hope i can

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION google_geocode( p_postcode varchar2 ) 
RETURN sdo_geometry IS
 l_http_req  utl_http.req;
 l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
 l_lat long;
 l_long long;
BEGIN

 l_http_req := utl_http.begin_request(
   url => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' || utl_url.escape(p_postcode)); 
 l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_req);

apex_json.parse (l_http_response);
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(apex_json.get_number('results.location.lat'));
--DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(apex_json.get_number('results.location.lng'));
l_lat := apex_json.get_number('results.location.lat');
l_long := apex_json.get_number('results.location.lng');



RETURN sdo_geometry
                    (
                    2001, 
                    4326,
                    sdo_point_type(
                                   TO_NUMBER(l_lat),
                                   TO_NUMBER(l_long),
                                   null),
                    null, 
                    null);
END google_geocode;
```

the errors im getting are, the first two i have since fixed but still get parsing error [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is stating there is no definition of `apex_json.parse` that matches the arguments you are trying to pass it.

If you look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_json.htm#AEAPI29742), you will see that there are four signatures for `parse`:

```
APEX_JSON.PARSE (
    p_values   in out nocopy t_values,
    p_source   in varchar2,
    p_strict   in boolean default true );

APEX_JSON.PARSE (
    p_values   in out nocopy t_values,
    p_source   in clob,
    p_strict   in boolean default true );

APEX_JSON.PARSE (
    p_source   IN VARCHAR2,
    p_strict   IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE );

APEX_JSON.PARSE (
    p_source   IN CLOB,
    p_strict   IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE );
```

Currently you are providing a single `utl_http.resp`, but there is no support for such a call.

You will need to read the data from your `utl_http.resp` object into a `CLOB` and then pass that to the `parse` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change variable name:

```
l_http_req := utl_http.begin_request(
   url => 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' 
           || utl_url.escape(p_postcode)); 


l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);  
                                         -- should be l_http_req
```

Comment: Hi, i dont suppose you have any further insight im still yet to to make progress on this